# Geht »Prot- und Deuteragonist«?

Tags: compound, hyphen

Beim [Ergänzungsstrich](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/bindestrich#K31) lässt man normalerweise vorne genau das weg, was die beiden Wörter gemeinsam haben, z.B. »tür« bei »Vorder- und Hintertür«. Bei [Protagonist](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Protagonist) und Deuteragonist wäre das -agonist. Passt zum griechischem Ursprung. Aber dann trennt man das Wort mitten in der Silbe. Geht das, »Prot-« zu schreiben? Man trennt es schließlich Pro-ta-go-nist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Alle Trennmöglichkeiten:](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Protagonist)

> Pro|t|a|go|nist

Daher kannst du Prot-agonist schreiben und folglich ist auch "Prot- und Deuteragonist" eine korrekte Schreibweise.

Comment: Man könnte noch hinzufügen, dass die Trennung aber nicht unbedingt unmittelbar allen verständlich ist. Insbesondere weil auch der Deuteragonist meines Erachtens viel seltener als der Protagonist gebraucht wird. Trotzdem +1

Comment: Ich kann mir nicht helfen, irgendwie sieht das sehr schräg aus. Vielleicht ein Fall, wo man eher doch "Protagonist und Deuteragonist" ausschreiben sollte.

Comment: Oder das ganze umgekehrt macht: "Deuter- und Protagonist". Wie gesagt, es ist **eine** korrekte Schreibweise. Eine von Vielen.

Comment: @SebastianK.: Nur dass der Protagonist (1. Schauspieler) eben vor dem Deuteragonisten (2. Schauspieler) kommt.